# How to get data from a database into a list of objects and display it in a listview?

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a simple contacts app and I encountered a problem with retrieving data from a database to a list of objects. I tried to do it without objects and then I noticed that this way is more used in practice. What I wanna do in this app is to show the name of the contact in a listview.

So here is my code:

```
public class Contact {

//private variables
int _id;
String _name;
String _phone_number;

// Empty constructor
public Contact(){

}

public Contact(String name){

    this._name=name;

}

// constructor
public Contact(int id, String name, String _phone_number){
    this._id = id;
    this._name = name;
    this._phone_number = _phone_number;
}

// constructor
public Contact(String name, String _phone_number){
    this._name = name;
    this._phone_number = _phone_number;
}
// getting ID
public int getID(){
    return this._id;
}

// setting id
public void setID(int id){
    this._id = id;
}

// getting name
public String getName(){
    return this._name;
}

// setting name
public void setName(String name){
    this._name = name;
}

// getting phone number
public String getPhoneNumber(){
    return this._phone_number;
}

// setting phone number
public void setPhoneNumber(String phone_number){
    this._phone_number = phone_number;
}

 @Override
public String toString() {
    return _name;
}

}
```

method in my DBHandler to retrieve all data:

```
 public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return contactList;
}
```

Method in my MainActivity to retrieve data(here is something wrong but cant figure it out):

```
 public void printDatabase() {


     List<Contact> listOfContacts = handler.getAllContacts();
    for (Contact cn : listOfContacts) {

        cn.getName();
        listOfContacts.add(cn);


    }




}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are getting all the contacts in `listofContacts` list? What exact problem are you facing? Post your logcat.

Comment: contact name is not being shown in the listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems :

1) As @RaviTeja pointed out, do all your initialization in onCreate() method, not inside a loop. Then, call `notifydatasetchanged()`.

2) 
Quoting the official documentation of ArrayAdapter :

> However the TextView is referenced, it will be filled with the
>   toString() of each object in the array. You can add lists or arrays of
>   custom objects. Override the toString() method of your objects to
>   determine what text will be displayed for the item in the list.

So, you know what to do. Implement the ToString() method in your `Contact` class to something like :

```
public String toString()
{
    return "name: "+_name;
}
```

Comment: so I added the toString method as shown in the updated topic. and I also moved the listview part to the on create method and remove the for loop. So how should my printDatabase method look like? cause I'm using it pretty often (after deleting contacts,adding etc..)

Comment: As per your use case, your print database should just update the list in adapter, and call 'notifydatasetchanged()' method.

Comment: No problem. If it solved your problem, you should accept the answer, so that up coming users on this page know what to do :)

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to initialise your listview and adapter inside a loop.

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview); //global
ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listOfContacts);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Move the above part of the code out of the for loop.No need of a loop.Place this code in your `onCreate()` and declare adapter globally.Then call `adapter.notfiyDataSetChanged()` after adding the contacts to the list.This will update the list.